# Where does Windows installer store current patch Sequence number for a particular product?

Tags: windows-installer, patch, msp

Where does Windows installer store currently installed patch [Sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370350(v=vs.85).aspx) number for a particular product?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this MSDN page (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371628(v=vs.85).aspx) it looks like windows installer patch sequence numbers are only stored in the cached MSIs/MSPs in the MsiPatchSequence table (not in the registry).

- *The **MsiDeterminePatchSequence** function takes a list of patches and determines in what sequence they can be applied to an installed product. This function accounts for any patches or products that have already been installed on the system.*
- *The **MsiDetermineApplicablePatches** function takes a list of patches and determines in what sequence they can be applied to an installed product. This function does not account for any patches or products that have already been installed on the system.*